# add word before and after a paragraph when pattern matches

Tags: regex, awk, sed

How can I add a word before (`valid`) and after (`<\valid>`) paragraph when pattern matchs (`-LEN`)  using sed or awk?

For example if I have the following file:

```
field FIELD1
     attributes DATATYPE something ,

field FIELD1-LEN
      attributes DATATYPE something ,
```

The result would be like:

```
field FIELD1
     attributes DATATYPE something ,
<valid>
field FIELD1-LEN
      attributes DATATYPE something ,
<\valid>
```

I have tried this sed command but I don't get the wanted result

```
sed -n   '/\-LEN/,/\ ,/i \<valid>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines **that is all**. All the sed constructs to do anything other than s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and experienced UNIX programmers use them today just for the mental exercise, not for their production code.

For anything more complicated than `s/old/new/` an awk solution will be clearer, simpler, more robust, more portable, more efficient, and easier to enhance in future than an equivalent sed solution.

```
$ awk -v RS= '/-LEN/{$0 = "<valid>\n" $0 "\n</valid>"} 1' file
field FIELD1
     attributes DATATYPE something ,
<valid>
field FIELD1-LEN
      attributes DATATYPE something ,
</valid>
```

Comment: Hey, that's not entirely fair. I still use advanced sed (hold space, branches) in production environments.  Job security!  (Oh, and nice answer btw. As usual.)

Comment: @ghoti my condolences and nice acknowledgement of the job security factor :-). You KNOW an awk script would be better in every significant way than whatever sed scripts you are using with hold space and branches (and yes, I'd be happy to show anyone a simpler, clearer, etc. equivalent awk script for any task that they think is best done in sed with hold space and/or branches). (And thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Set the record separator as a paragraph and check if the record contains `LEN`:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/LEN/{print "<valid>"} 1; /LEN/{print "</valid>"}' a
field FIELD1
     attributes DATATYPE something ,
<valid>
field FIELD1-LEN
      attributes DATATYPE something ,
</valid>
```

Comment: @malmo there probably is, but probably way more complicated. Why does the technology matters? Better try to find the best tool for each job.

Comment: @fedorqui, Is there any particular benefit to doing three separate awk statements with two regexp evaluations rather than the single evaluation with concatenation as Ed Morton suggested?

Comment: @ghoti none. I just couldn't think on Ed Morton's approach and, instead, checked the input twice. So his answer is obviously better.

Comment: Ah, very few can match Ed's combination of speed and quality. You still get my +1 for being first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little complicated sed script:

```
sed -i 'N;s/\(-LEN\(.\|\n\)*,\)/\1\n<\/value>/g;P;D' fields.txt && sed -i 's/^\(.*-LEN\)/<value>\n\1/g' fields.txt
```

Too bad that I don't fully understand what the `N;`, `;P` and `;D` does in the 1st regex. You can find more on multiline regexes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4511290/187808).

Another mystery for me is that I cannot combine the two regex with the usual `-e` switch.

So, this regex works, but use it cautiously.